# Conditional Distribution inference

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, bivariate-distributions

Let $X, Y$ have a joint uniform distribution on the unit square.
Thus,
$$f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y) = 
\begin{cases} 1 &0\leq x\leq1 \\
                       0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Given $Y=y, X$ is Uniform$(0,1)$. We can write this as $X|Y=y∼$Uniform$(0,1)$.

How did it derive $$f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y) = 
\begin{cases} 1 &0\leq x\leq1 \\
                       0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
And how did we get $X|Y=y∼$Uniform$(0,1)$?

Comment: I suggest you start by adding the definitions that confuse you to this post.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Do you know what is the definition of joint density function? density function? Cumulative distribution function? Your question is basically on the definitions you are using. One could say this is usually the case in math, but I think it is more "noticable" here.

Comment: Yes, I know what they are.

Comment: If $(X,Y)$ is jointly uniform on the unit square, then $X$ and $Y$ are independent with a uniform distribution on $(0,1)$. So conditional distribution is same as unconditional distribution. Is that what you are asking?